various file types (e.g., .png, .jpg), are not supported while trying to send them through PowerAutomate
Here is my attempted solution, I did according to the instructions from this link

Inside Append to array variable action I entered below-mentioned code inside Value property of the action:
{
  "Name": "@{items('For_each')?['DisplayName']}",
  "ContentBytes": "@{base64(body('Get_attachment_content'))}",
  "ContentType": "@{items('For_each')?['contentType']}"
}


And it says "it is not supported". Several file types like .png, .jpg and others cannot be either viewed or downloaded.
Can anyone help to handle the issue?

Not found any issue sending jpg or png  files from Power Apps to SharePoint Document Library or sending as email attachment by running a Power Automate Flow.
I'm not sure why you're using base64() to convert the content bytes. In my sample flow (tested with single attachment, but it would work the same for multiple), I'm sending the content bytes as-is.
triggerBody()['file']['name']

triggerBody()['file']['contentBytes']





It worked, many thanks!
